# Error: I18nextWithTranslation suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am trying to get I18N working using react-i18next. I am following the steps provided [here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks) as close as possible. I have tried for several hours with lots of googling around and have not yet discovered what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

I am getting this Error stack trace:

```
    Exception has occurred: Error
Error: I18nextWithTranslation suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
    in I18nextWithTranslation (created by App)
    in App
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in CookiesProvider
    at throwException (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:45969:13)
    at renderRoot (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:47147:11)
    at performWorkOnRoot (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:48000:7)
    at performWork (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:47912:7)
    at performSyncWork (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:47886:3)
    at requestWork (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:47755:5)
    at scheduleWork (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:47569:5)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:48230:3)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:48258:10)
    at updateContainer (https://localhost:3000/cgadmin-react-primeng/dist/bundle.js:48315:10)
```

I have a Suspense with fallback at the very top level:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import App from "./App.js";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import i18n (needs to be bundled ;)) 
import './i18n';

ReactDOM.render(
  <CookiesProvider>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/cgadmin-react-primeng/">
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <App />
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </CookiesProvider>, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);

const Loader = () => (
  <div>loading...</div>
);
```

I am not using hooks, but rather the HOC recomended for use with classes on the App class like this:

```
export default withTranslation()(App);
```

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue. In my case I'm not even using Suspense in that part of the application.

Answer (score 32):

By default useSuspense is set to true so React needs fallback UI. Setting useSuspense to false will solve your problem as React will not need fallback UI anymore.

```
i18n
    .init({
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank! This parameter in react section has solved my issue.

Comment: thanks, it solved for me too, but i wasn't using Suspense in the top layer, still helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I've solved wrapping my render on `<Suspense>`, you can find more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense

And in i18next said the same in its documentation https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks#translate-your-content

-

also

```
i18n
    .init({
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        }
    });
```

The previous code works, but left many warnings, the best way is use `<Suspense>`

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a more specific example on the error situation? I have try my best simulate in sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/10j2xw6j3), but I can't reproduce the case.

p.s. This should be added in comment, but stackoverflow stop new users from doing that. So I post here and edit later

Comment: I am not really sure if I can make it much simpler. I followed all the instructions. As soon as I add withTranslation to any of my class files, I get the error and my app no longer runs. Does it matter at all that I am trying to load the translations via a rest call?

Comment: Also, my code uses withTranslation to wrap a class that is already wrapped. Does that matter?

Comment: I get this error too - I do not have a fallback UI, but it still should not happen. I do think the withTranslation makes the issue happen. For me, it is not every time, though, it is just sometimes and on some boxes...

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, could it be because you're defining `Loader` *after* you're using it?

Comment: I thought of that too. I moved it ahead and no luck. I made it a separate component and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XHR (i18next-xhr-backend), then you need to wrap your app into a Suspense component:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <h1>{t('Welcome to React')}</h1>
}

// i18n translations might still be loaded by the xhr backend
// use react's Suspense
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable suspend! Add resources to your init:

```
i18n.init({
    resources: {},
});
```